# Recursive Function in OCaml return Unbound Value Error

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

I'm getting Unbound Value Error in visual studio when trying to use OCaml

Tried restarting App.

```
let rec contains elt l = 
    match l with
    | [] -> false
    |x ::xs ->
        if x = elt then
            true
        else 
            contains(xs)
```

Comment: The code provided does not produce said error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any unbound values being used in this code. What is the exact error message you're seeing?

There is a type error, which could lead to other problems down the line, perhaps.

Your recursive call to `contains` passes just one argument. But `contains` is expecting two arguments.

**Update**

Here's what an unbound value error looks like in OCaml (the usual INRIA release at least):

```
# let x = abc;;
Error: Unbound value abc
```

So if your error message literally says "unbound value error", then you are trying to use a value named `error` that isn't defined.

I actually tend to doubt this. It really would help if you could copy/paste the exact error message.

Comment: hmm that seems to be the issue. The exact error was unbound value error. How could I change my code to accept two arguments?

Comment: Your code already accepts two arguments. You need to *pass* two arguments. You have `contains (xs)`. You should have `contains elt xs`.

Comment: let rec remove_elts l reml =
  match l with
    [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
      if contains x reml then
    remove_elts xs reml
      else
    x :: removes_elts xs reml
;;

Comment: let rec remove_elts l reml =
  match l with
    [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
      if contains x reml then
    remove_elts xs reml
      else
    x :: removes_elts xs reml
;; This also returns an unbound error. The exact error in visual studio is Error: Unbound value remove_elts